# after thread sleep TextView is not printing vlaue

Tags: android, multithreading

tv value set to value 1 then after 5000 it does not set its value , showdown the app

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

    Thread  time = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        try{
            tv.setText("Value 1");
            sleep(5000);
            tv.setText("Value 2");
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            tv.setText("Value 3");
        }
        }
    };
    time.start();
```

Comment: Because accessing `tv.setText` from non-ui Thread  :)

Comment: @Usman Mustafa, put your try catch code inside runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `Activity.runOnUiThread()` to update the UI from other threads.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Value 1");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**OR**

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
Thread t =new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Value 1");
                }
            });
        }
    }};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the code that deals with UI on the main thread... it's called UIThread... you can do any thing on another threads except handling UI

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    tv.setText....

}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the TextView update method inside the `runOnUiThread()` method. Your code should look something like this:

```
Thread time = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Value 1");
                }
            });

            sleep(5000);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Value 2");
                }
            });

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            tv.setText("Value 3");
        }
    }
};
time.start();
```

Comment: Still posted solution hang Ui Thread because `sleep(5000);` is called inside `runOnUiThread`